# Way to insert a code into a page by user input

Tags: javascript, php, input, submit

I have a website for testing purposes, and one of them is testing particular codes (popup/static forms).

1. I would like to create a solution where I can simply put the code into a e.g. form text area, and it would submit/paste it into another page's code. The code to be pasted is a javascript. That way, visiting the page afterwards, the javascript form (popup, form) runs automatically, no need to call anything there.
2. Another step would be deleting that code afterwards to allow insertion of a new one.

I have knowledge in basic PHP (just learning), and thought about using the `fwrite()` - is that a bad idea?

Comment: Accepting user input that isn't sanitized is a dangerous road that leads to cross site scripting and other attack vectors. If it's because you want to test something have you tried looking at e2e test tools like Cypress?

Comment: @Webbanditten Thanks for the response. I should have thought about security. I looked at Cypress but from what I gathered, I am not sure if that's what I need. I need something to provide for my colleague(s), something very user friendly, as they are not coders, so they could insert a piece of javascript and be able to delete it afterwards aswell.